# VB publishing error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to publish an application I am working on and am receiving the following error...

Error   1   Failed to connect to 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'C:\Users\me\Desktop'.  Unable to create the Web site location 'C:\Users\me\Desktop'.  Access is denied.

I am not trying to publish to a website so don't understand why it is presenting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have chose the right application for the project in the first place. but the error is indicating that its trying to load a website, while your writing or normal programming application. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and cannot identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running you program from a network location, as I am, you can change your Install Mode Mode and Settings to "The application is available online only".

1. Open your Project
2. Click the "Project" menu
3. Select "Properties" as the last item in the drop down menu
4. Select "Publish" from the list on the left
5. Change your Install Mode & Settings.

This worked for me...